# How to make a Java console output a environment variable in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, output, environment-variables

I am new to Jenkins and even though I found a few similar questions, none of the solutions seemed to work for me the way I need it to. It might look like a basic problem to some but for me it's a very big deal that I'm struggling with.

Basically, I built a project that executes Java Selenium code, which displays session ID in Jenkins' Console Output and that's what I need to add to environment variables to be used in the projects triggered after completion of this one.

I tried some Groovy scripts but I don't think I understand enough how to work with it and so whatever I was given, wasn't what I hoped to get.

Has anyone done something similar to provide some tips on how to achieve that?

Many thanks

Comment: Is the printing of the _session ID_ under your control or do you have to trace the Console Output for it?

Comment: Could you alter the selenium code to write the values you need into a properties file? Or maybe write a script to parse the build log and extract it for you?

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE Your first sentence is exactly what I had in mind with the first part of my comment. Regarding your second sentence there is a plugin that can do that.

Comment: @I-LOVE-2-REVIVE Unfortunately the plugin I referred to doesn't do what it is supposed to do (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38243472/1744774)). So, your _parse script_ suggestion seems to be the only solution for the second case atm.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options (in theory, one of them doesn't work, see 2. below) depending on whether the printing is under your control or not.

1. Printing is under your control:

   - Write the session ID to a properties file, e.g. `from-build-log.properties`:

     ```
     sessionId=...
     ```
   - <kbd>***Add post-build action***</kbd> → [*Trigger parameterized build on other projects*](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) → [image]

     > This plugin triggers builds on other projects, with parameters that are predefined, or supplied by the finished build.
     >
     > Every parameter will be passed to the target project(s), even if the target is not parameterized, or if no property of that name is defined.

     - <kbd>***Add parameters***</kbd> → *Parameters from properties file*

       - *Use properties from file*: `from-build-log.properties`
2. Printing is *not* under your control:

   - <kbd>***Add post-build action***</kbd> → [*Post build task*](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) → [image]:

     > This feature allows you to associate shell or a batch scripts that perform some tasks on Hudson depending on the build log output. If the log text matches somewhere in the build log file, the script will execute. [...]
     >
     > Java Regex are allowed, and groups can be used as script parameters. If the text is "Last Build : #(\d+)" and the script is "script.sh", then if the log contains a line "Last Build : #4", the script "script.sh 4" will be called.

     - *Tasks*  → *Script* → [image]:

       > [...] References %1, .. %n are allowed, and will be replaced by the groups matched by the Regex. %0 is the whole match.

     ---

     Unfortunately this doesn't to work since there is an issue known since 2013: [[JENKINS-17268] Post build task plugin: Passing arguments does not work as documented](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17268).

     - ***Build*** → ***Execute Windows batch command*** → *Command*:

       ```
       @echo( & echo   CMD: sessionId=123456789
       ```
     - ***Post build task*** → *Tasks*:

       - *Log text*: `sessionId=(\d+)`
       - *Script*:

         ```
         @echo( & echo   sessionId='%1'(!) of '%0'
         ```

     Console Output:

     ```
     ...
     [Freestyle-project] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson4684581005071706054.bat

       CMD: sessionId=123456789

     C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Freestyle-project>exit 0 
     Performing Post build task...
     Match found for :sessionId=(\d+) : True
     Logical operation result is TRUE
     Running script  : @echo( & echo   sessionId='%1'(!) of '%0'

     [Freestyle-project] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1525182929053902824.bat

       sessionId=''(!) of 'C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson1525182929053902824.bat'

     C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Freestyle-project>exit 0 
     POST BUILD TASK : SUCCESS
     END OF POST BUILD TASK : 0
     Finished: SUCCESS
     ```

     `%0` is not the "*the whole match*" but the script's name, as usual with Windows command line. `%1` is empty.

     ---

     A workaround is:
   - <kbd>***Add build step***</kbd> → *Execute shell* → *Command*:

     ```
     sed -En 's/.*(sessionId=[0-9]+)/\1/p' \
       ../../jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log > from-build-log.properties
     ```
   - <kbd>***Add post-build action***</kbd> → *Trigger parameterized build on other projects*

     - <kbd>***Add parameters***</kbd> → *Parameters from properties file*

       - *Use properties from file*: `from-build-log.properties`